# Does the following voltage regulator have a specific name?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

[image]
The reference voltage is taken from the potentiometer.

Comment: The reference voltage is taken from ZD, the potentiometer divides the reference voltage to the value you want to set.

Comment: I thought the reference voltage is the one at (+).

Comment: Do you mean (+) as in the + input on the opamp? If so, you're correct. That is where the reference voltage (Vref) is entering the opamp, but Vref is being set by the pot next to ZD.

Comment: I hereby name thee *Carl*.

Comment: I'm not convinced about that current limit...

Comment: I think it might be called "crude series regulator with lots of voltage dropout, rough current limit (with 2 fighting transistors) and reverse voltage protection (with no gate protection for the PFET)" but I'm not sure if it has a shorter name :-)

Comment: it's not something I'd want to remember for long enough to give it a name.

Comment: Does  anyone have an idea what the Mosfet is doing there?

Comment: @Shemafied I believe the mosfet is being used as the reverse voltage protection.

Comment: For line stability, it is usual to connect R1 to the regulated output rather than the unregulated input, though there is a boot-strapping issue to get it started, usually a capacitor and diode to bias the zener until the output comes up.

Comment: @But R1 also comes as a overcurrent protection for the Zener diode?

Comment: @Shemafeld I would not use this circuit as is. It has a high dropout voltage and that reverse protection circuit need some over-voltage protection of its own. The current limit is just bad.

Comment: "POS" comes to mind...

Comment: I'd call this '723 reloaded'

Comment: You might call it an "HDO".  Though POS isn't bad either.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen The \$\mu\$A723 is a gem compared to this turd.

Comment: Q1 has no gate protection so it will blow up an maybe 20V in .

Comment: Yep, I'll see tomorrow what it can really handle, and I will post the results here

Comment: Consider this cct a learning exercise. | This appears to be a very old circuit (or based on very old circuits) except for Q1 which is newer but could still be oldish. The op-amp pinout is that of an LM741 opamp [**LM741 datasheet here**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) which is VERY VERY old and which has major limitations in sense and drive voltages when used in this circuit. Even using a still very old LM324 would be better here. There are much better circuits around. | Replace Q2 Q3 with a single MOSFET - far less drive and more  ....

Comment: .... | Swap polarity of output device (P Channel FET) allows much closer Vout approach to VinDC. "Proper" current limit and maybe foldback (depending on use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a "Linear series regulator", linear because the components operate in their linear regions, series because the regulation operates in series with it's load.
And BTW, the current limit circuit is called a clamp, although a crappily implemented one, that will blow itself to pieces when it's needed...
As for the MOSFET at the input, vini_i is right in assuming it is a reverse polarity protection.

Comment: You can find an explanation of the protection circuit at http://www.irf.com/technical-info/designtp/dt94-8.pdf

Comment: Bad current limit circuit: What is protecting Q4 from blowing up under extreme load? Q2 emitter can supply enough current to destroy it, and possibly itself too.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit is trying to be a "linear regulator".  That means it ideally puts out a constant voltage from a higher varying input voltage.  The LM7805 is a common example of a linear regulator all in a 3 pin package.  It can take from about 7.5 to 35 volts in, and make a steady 5 V out.

This particular linear regulator has a pretty high *headroom* or *dropout voltage*.  That's the difference between the minimum required input voltage and the output voltage.  It requires the B-E drops of Q2 and Q3, plus whatever headroom the opamp needs between its positive supply and maximum output voltage.  The total could be 2 V or more.  That's quite a lot by today's standards.  Even the old LM7805 only requires about 2.5 V.

This is definitely not a LDO (low dropout) regulator.  I guess you could call it a HDO regulator for fun, but that's not really a name.  Nobody advertises their non-LDO regulators as specifically having high dropout.  They just don't say anything and quietly list the dropout voltage in the specifications.

Q4 with R2 and R3 appears to be a crude attempt at current limiting, but the way it's hooked up won't yield very good results.

You can do better with about the same parts.